# Why didn't java let me call this protected function

Tags: java, syntax, methods, protected

Suppose following class Structure:

inside namespace a

```
public abstract class A {

    protected int someVal;
    protected abstract int action();

}
```

in namespace a.b

```
public class B extends A{

    //magically filled with elements ;)
    List<A> elements; 

    protected int action(){
        someVal = 42; // OK
        int l = 0;
        for (A a : elements){
            l+= a.action(); //FORBIDDEN!!
        }
        return l;
    }
}
```

so Eclipse suggests me to

> Change the visibility of 'action' to 'protected'

I feel some kind of fooled.

Why I'm allowed to implement action, but not to call it? I have no problem accessing `someVal` either.

I'm well aware of copying `B` into the same namespace, but I have many Classes which extend B or similiar C's and D's etc. and like to have them in order.

Or to rephrase my Question:
Is this packet 'thingy' the only way to force my classes to have a protected method, but hide that from client code?

Comment: It's because `a.action()` is **abstract**, which typically means it's defined by the base class but isn't implemented until a descendant does so. There's no `base.action()` to access.

Comment: What type of objects list A have??

Comment: @KenWhite I have a list of actual implementations of `A` which were all forced to implement `action()`. Therefore there can't be lack of that method

Comment: @Renjith is this really of matter? maybe B maybe C or CC which extends from C.... There are implementations of `A`

Comment: Actual implementations of `a` would imply a descendant which actually implements `a.action()`. An **implementation** would actually implement the **abstract** method by definition. Read again what I wrote in my comment. I think you need to read the documentation regarding what `abstract` means. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite I think you are wrong! If i change `abstract` modifier of `action()` method, and return 0, I have the same error! As Eclipse states: this is an ACCESS Problem

Comment: Indeed, if `A.action` had default access ("package private"), then it wouldn't be implementable or overrideable in the different package of `B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a static typing perspective `a` may not be an instance of `B`. You can't touch the protecteds of a non-descendent class (except via the same package get out). `protected` should be used rarely, if at all.

Comment: I thought protected means 'beeing visible to this and subclasses or classes inside the package'. Why I have access to someVal which has the same keyword?

Comment: @RafaelIT - read that again.  Note that B is not in/inside the package of A.

Comment: @RafaelT `someVal` is effectively `this.someVal`. `this` is statically an instance of `B`. (Similarly implementing `action` is on `this` (a `B`), whilst the `a.action()` is called on an `A`.)